# Box Content API : Passing a folder description as you create it

Tags: c#, .net, box

Using Box Content API and the .Net SDK, is it possible to specify a description to be used as the folder description when you create a folder ? So far I was only able to do it using the Update folder method and after the folder was created :
https://box-content.readme.io/reference#update-information-about-a-folder

Same question on Box forum : https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/Box-Content-API-Is-modified-at-field-of-parent-folder-updated/m-p/15437#U15437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add a folder description at the time of creating a folder via the Box API.

As you mentioned, you can add a folder description after creating a folder using the Update Folder API endpoint.